# How to get coordinates from html to mark on Leaflet map?

Tags: javascript, css, json, leaflet

I was trying to find a solution for map marking and found Leaflet today. I also found perfect sample usage fits my project, but in that example, they use a separate JSON file to get map markers info.

Here is the example I found: https://demo.bootstrapious.com/directory/1-2/category-2.html

when you check to the source code you will see it uses

```
<script>
  createListingsMap({
      mapId: 'categorySideMap',
      jsonFile: 'js/restaurants-geojson.62620b3d.json'
  });

</script>
```

In that json file all the coordinates and info windows data is stored

Instead of this, I want to use meta tags to list the info the map needs. I actually just need to get long and lat info and use the same info I use for regular listing (like title,pic)

I can list it something like that :

```
<meta id="longlat" name="build-id"  content="39.88498,-82.99005" />
```

But don't know how to do the Leaflet map creating codes.

Would you please help me?

p.s: I'm using php

Comment: Hey there, have you tried looking at the soruce code of `createListingsMap` ? You can access by looking at the source code of the demo page.
I think that would be a good starting point for you to understand how to provide data for your own markers (ugly idea: inject them via php into a global variable **before** populating the markers)

Comment: I already know createListingMap , I already mentioned about it in the question. I want to learn how to provide the data inside of the page not from an external json.